# Adding laravel cronjob in hosting server using cpanel

Tags: php, laravel

How to add new `laravel` cronjob in the hosting server using cpamel?

Comment: I spent hours working with this so I don't want anyone to spent much time into this either because sharing is caring.

Comment: It might be better to split this into a separate question and answer rather than have the answer contained in the question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not to made to share code, it's made for answering questions.

Comment: remember that php might be /usr/bin/php o usr/bin/ea-php72 or similar

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine please, add your answer in the right section.

Answer (score 0):

as  for me am using laravel 5.4, namecheap hosting and your question/answer helped me after days of research
and this is what i finally used that works

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/separatefolder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```